# WebpackError: TypeError: p5__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default.a is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, gatsby, p5.js, netlify, ml5.js

**This server is running fine in develop mode but throws an error during production build**

I'm using Gatsby.js Framework and currently, my codes are deployed on netlify server.

*Here is my gatsby-node.js config file:*

```js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /ml5/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
          {
            test: /p5/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

**Error Output: **
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyZMm.png)

**Here are the codes in the experiments.js file**

```js
import React from "react"
import MetaData from "../components/MetaData"
import ml5 from "ml5"
import "../components/styles.css"
import p5 from "p5"

export default function Experiments() {
  let label = ""
  let probability = ""
  let classifier
  let video

  const gotResult = (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
    } else {
      label = result[0].label.toUpperCase()

      probability = (result[0].confidence * 100).toFixed(2)
      classifier.classify(gotResult)
    }
  }

  const modelOnLoaded = () => {
    console.log("Model is Successfully Loaded!")
  }

  const videoReady = () => {
    classifier.classify(gotResult)
  }

  function sketch(p) {
    p.setup = () => {
      p.createCanvas(640, 480)

      video.hide()
      p.background(0)
    }
    p.draw = () => {
      p.background(0)
      p.image(video, 0, 0)
      p.fill(0)
      p.textSize(32)
      p.text(label, 10, p.height - 100)
      p.text(probability, 10, p.height - 30)
    }
    p.preload = () => {
      video = p.createCapture(p.VIDEO, videoReady)

      classifier = ml5.imageClassifier("MobileNet", video, modelOnLoaded)
    }
  }

  new p5(sketch)

  return (
    <div>
      <MetaData />
      <h1 className="display-1">Image Classifier</h1>

      <div></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Machine Specification:

```
System:
    OS: Linux 5.4 Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz
    Shell: 5.8 - /usr/bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.20.0 - /usr/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.10 - /usr/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 87.0.4280.88
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.26.1 => 2.26.1
    gatsby-plugin-load-script: ^1.1.0 => 1.1.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.9.0 => 2.9.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.7.0 => 3.7.0
    gatsby-source-github-api: ^0.2.1 => 0.2.1
    gatsby-source-graphql: ^2.11.0 => 2.11.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.16.2
```

Comment: If you remove those `null` loaders, it bothers you the `window` isn't it?

Comment: Yeah!, Then it will throw an error about the `window` is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the offending module is not the dependency itself (`p5` and `ml5` in this case) and is one of the dev-dependencies of that libraries. For example, in a project of mine, I'm showing a map and the map library is outputting the same as your issue, I had to add a `null` loader to `/canvg/` in my case, a library that is using my map to print it.

Another solution from the [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/#fixing-third-party-modules) that may fit for you is using [loadable-components](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components), basically, instead of adding a `null` loader in the build-time, it loads the dependency on the client-side (and not on the server-side). In your case:

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component'

const YourFunctionToUseMl5 = loadable(() => import ml5 from "ml5")
const YourFunctionToUseP5 = loadable(() => import p5 from "p5")


function MyComponent() {
 useEffect(()=>{
   // use safely ml5 and p5
 }, [])

  return (
    <div>
     Hello loadable
    </div>
  )
}
```

Use it carefully because despite being a low-size dependency, you are using a non-native approach (as `null` loader is) and it may increase the bundled size of the application.

Comment: I did the same but still, it is showing the error: TypeError: p5 is not a constructor

Comment: Are you sure that `p5` is a react importable library? I don't think so and I haven't found information about that so I guess that is a native JavaScript library, not a React one

Comment: Yeah, you are right. You can't directly import p5 in the react application instead I use [react-p5-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5-wrapper) and it works!